# European Union enshrines net zero and emissions targets in law

Tags: conjunctions, error

The following is a headline from CNN. Is "and" out of place?

> European Union enshrines net zero **and** emissions targets in law

Comment: Possibly not. Without reading the article, the emissions targets could refer to stages while net zero could refer to a final target.

Comment: "net zero" is supposed to be an adjective modifying "emissions." As the headline is written, "net zero" and "emissions targets" are juxtaposed. But what exactly is "emissions targets"?

Comment: In this headline I expect that "net zero emissions" is shortened to "net zero" and "emissions targets" refers to something else. I imagine the law sets a date when CO2 emissions must be zero, and earlier dates with their own, non-zero, targets. I may be wrong - if in doubt about what the headline should say then read the entire article. Remember the purpose of the headline is to get you to read the article, not necessarily to be a good summary.

Comment: https://edition.cnn.com/2021/06/28/europe/eu-climate-change-law-net-zero-intl/index.html

Comment: While "emissions targets" alone could function as an object, it is not descriptive enough.

Comment: @Apollyon ""net zero" is supposed to be an adjective modifying "emissions."  - no, it is not.

Comment: Another thing about the headline is, "net zero" itself could refer to a kind of emissions target. lexico.com/definition/net_zero If so, the coordination of "net zero" and 'emissions targets" could be problematic just like "huskies and dogs."

Answer (score 2):

From a comment to the question:

> "net zero" is supposed to be an adjective modifying "emissions."

No, [net zero](https://medialibrary.climatecentral.org/resources/what-is-net-zero) is a term of its own. It basically means

> ... that any greenhouse gas emissions released are balanced by an equal amount being taken out of the atmosphere.

[Emissions targets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissions_target) are stated targets on how much emissions are to be reduced by a certain date. For example, according to [this overview from Australia](https://www.climatechangeauthority.gov.au/comparing-countries-emissions-targets)

- The UK plans to get down to 50% below 1990 levels by 2023-2027
- Germany plans to get down to 55% below 1990 by 2030

So, according to

> European Union enshrines net zero and emissions targets in law

the proposed law covers net zero *and* emissions targets. The conjunction is completely correct.

Comment: I suspect the author meant to write "net-zero emissions targets."

Comment: "Net zero" is supposed to be used as an adjective.

Comment: https://edition.cnn.com/2021/06/28/europe/eu-climate-change-law-net-zero-intl/index.html

Comment: Otherwise, "emissions targets" alone would not be descriptive enough.

Comment: @Apollyon No, as I explained in my answer, both "net zero" and "emissions target" are established terms in the field.

Comment: @Apollyon - Henning Kockerbeck explained very clearly. The CNN headline says that the proposed law covers (1) net zero **and** (2) emission targets. Net zero is a noun phrase meaning 'an exact balance between the amount of greenhouse gas produced and the amount removed from the atmosphere'. It is **one** thing in the headline, which **also** mentions the requirement for the 27 EU countries to reduce greenhouse emissions by 55% by 2030 (from 1990 levels).

Comment: @Apollyon - if you read the story, you will understand the headline.

Comment: @Apollyon ""Net zero" is supposed to be used as an adjective. " - it is not.

Comment: Another thing about the headline is, "net zero" itself could refer to a kind of emissions target. lexico.com/definition/net_zero If so, the coordination of "net zero" and 'emissions targets" could be problematic just like "huskies and dogs."

Comment: @Apollyon No, net zero can't refer to a kind of emissions target. The definition you linked doesn't support that, either. Net zero looks at the net change of emissions that are in the atmosphere - how much gets added, minus how much gets removed. An emissions target only deals with how much gets added (or how much somebody promises to add at most). I'm afraid you're on the wrong track here.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck I understand "net zero" refers to the amount of emissions that are to be offset. But supposedly there is a limit to the amount of compensatory action that could be taken, and that limit will in turn put a limit on the amount of greenhouse gases a signatory state could produce. That effectively translates a net-zero target into an emissions target.

Comment: In other words, there are no net-zero targets that are not emissions targets at the same time. Every net-zero target is an emissions target.

Comment: @Apollyon I'm afraid that's not correct. Net zero means that for any emissions you add to the atmosphere, you have remove the same amount. It doesn't say how big this amount is, or could be. If you add, for example, 10 tons of CO2 equivalent, you have to remove the same amount - 500 kilos of CO2 equivalent, you have to remove the same amount, 500 kilos of CO2 equivalent. If you add 10 tons, you have to remove 10 tons.

Comment: @Apollyon On the other hand, emissions targets handle the absolute values you can add (or the values you promise to stay below). Here, how much you remove from the atmosphere or not doesn't come into play at all.

Comment: Do you agree "Net zero" refers to the balance, the final result. It refers not only to the removal of CO2, but also to decreasing its production.?

Comment: @Apollyon Net zero refers _only_ to the balance, without regard to how much has been added and needs to be compensated. You can blast tons and tons into the atmosphere - as long as you remove the same amount again, you've reached net zero. But you've probably broken any emissions target in existence.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, both *"net zero"* and especially *"emissions targets"* sound unnatural and straight from the dictionary and grammar of something like Orwellian newspeak. It is purposefully difficult to argue about the correctness of recently made-up artificial constructs related to the "climate change scare" agenda like this. I would suggest not giving too much thought about minutiae like this; it is confusing whether the "and" is out of place because it is meant to be confusing, with the goal of causing a mental fatigue, which in turn lowers readers' guard and easies the effort of pushing agenda.

Comment: Another thing about the headline is, "net zero" itself could refer to a kind of emissions target. lexico.com/definition/net_zero If so, the coordination of "net zero" and 'emissions targets" could be problematic just like "huskies and dogs."